# Get executed scheduled tasks in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.1

In Kernel.php I have several tasks that runs once or twice a day.

When I call `php artisan schedule:run` in the console I can see a response with "No scheduled commands are ready to run" or "Running scheduled command: xxxx".

I want to retrieve this messages to store them while running `function schedule(Schedule $schedule){}` in Kernel.php

The last think I tried is using `ob_start();` and `ob_get_contents();` but theese only returns my own `echo();`.

Adding `->getSummaryForDisplay()` to the register command line doesn't display if a command was executed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the output as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#task-output):

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')
    ->daily()
    ->sendOutputTo($filePath);
```

to save the output to a file. Or:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')
     ->daily()
     ->appendOutputTo($filePath);
```

to append it to a file.

You can also get the output by email but I believe you'll still have to use a file as well.

Comment: I had tried `->sendOutputTo($filePath);` but nothing happened. I'm using the $schedule->call() method and `sendOutputTo` seems to work only with the `command` method. 
On the other hand I would like to save the output to the database, not to a file.